# Postfix configuration: how to manage locally sent email from cron jobs?

Tags: postfix

I set up Postfix on a Debian server serving from mydomain.com and configured it to send out emails from mydomain.com email addresses.

Since switching to this configuration, my gmail started to be flooded by emails of the outputs of cronjobs that run on my user account on the server. Apparently, the emails get automatically sent to me@mydomain.com which Postfix sends out instead of keeping locally for the "me" debian user account email.

How can I change the configuration so that such emails only remain in the local mailbox of the user on the server?

Comment: Fix the cronjobs so that they don't generate output on success.

Answer (score 0):

Those emails are actually sent to the local `root` user, which perhaps you have inadvertently aliased to me@mydomain.com. Check /etc/aliases. There's a number of other things you could have got wrong also. Do you have virtual hosts? What's your `mydestination` set to? What the envelope 'From' address on those emails?